# iOS: Standard rules to follow when implementing drawRect: with draggable objects

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, touch, drawrect

My app allows the user to drag circles around on a screen. I'm wondering whether there are any standard steps to take in order to implement this, especially in regards to marking the correct areas of the view as dirty. I'm currently doing the following:

```
//Get initial touch point and draw a circle there. Use touch point and size of circle to pass the mark the appropriate CGRect as dirty so that it gets redrawn
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

//Get new touchpoint and draw a circle there. Use the union of the previous CGRect and the new one (based on the touch point and circle size) to tell drawRect: what area of the screen to redraw.
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

Does this seem right, or is there some other fundamental piece that I should be doing?

Comment: Did you intend to add more code? Or are you just saying you implemented those methods?

Comment: I didn't intend to add more code because I'm not worried about the specifics of the implementation, just the broader conceptual steps that should be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your view is what is drawing the circles, then what you're doing should be fine. Just use `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect: circleRect]` to mark the previous and new positions of the circle as dirty.

Comment: of course. was just looking for confirmation on the prior steps. thx.